# Should I use Elassandra instead of Cassandra to be able to use Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, connector, elassandra

I am trying to integrate my Cassandra database with Elastic search but it seems the previous DataStax connector is deprecated and the only way of doing this is using Elassandra?

I want to make sure if Elassandra is a reliable alternative for Cassandra and there is not an easy way of using Cassandra + Elasticsearch?

PS: I don't have any previous data in my Cassandra db and if there is an easy way I can index data from the beginning and use these indexes by Elasticsearch this is a good option for me.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the latency between when data is written and when you need it to appear in elastic search, I would consider using CDC for Apache Cassandra, which will push data insertions / mutations onto an Apache Pulsar topic, this can then be configured to sink to Elastic / any other consumers of the data.

This has the advantage of single responsibility for each component and allows the Cassandra and elastic to scale independently of each other.